# Aligning a minted block and a figure in a subfigure setting

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, minted

I am trying to create a Figure where on the left side I have an actual figure while on the right side I have some code using the minted package. At the moment I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted} % for making code snippets
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.975,0.95,1.0}

\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, bgcolor =bg, frame=lines,framesep=2mm]{julia}
he = Systems.henon()
N, α = 100000, 2
tr = trajectory(he, N)
ε = estimate_boxsizes(tr)
ε = 10 .^ (-6:0.25:0)
H = genentropy.(α, ε, Ref(tr))
plot(-log10.(ε), log10.(H))
\end{minted}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

No matter what combination of `t, t!, b, b!` I've tried, I can't seem to get the minted environment and the figure to align properly so that they have exactly the same top (or bottom).

What's the solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (not tested:) try adding `\vspace{0pt}` right at the beginning of the `subfigure` environments. Also, the `!` is invalid there. Valid options are `t`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: Hi thanks. Removing the ! **and** adding the `\vspace` made it work. Maybe post it as a normal answer?

Comment: I added an explanation why this trick works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertical alignment you want is tricky because TeX doesn't see things as you see them. TeX sees each of the `subfigure` environments (which are actually just fancy `minipage`s) as a box, the same it sees the box of the character `z`, for example, but bigger.

The `minipage` with your picture is like a (very large) character: its box has a width (you set it to `0.5\textwidth`), a height, which is the height of the image, a depth, which is zero, and the picture sits on the baseline.

The `minipage` with the code is much like other `minipage`s with text: it has a bunch of lines, one on top of the other, and each of them with its own baseline.

The vertical alignment options `t`, `c`, and `b` mean that the `minipage` will use either a `\vtop`, `\vcenter`, or `\vbox` for its contents. Here's what they do:

- A `\vbox` sets the baseline of the entire box to match the baseline of the last (bottom) line of the box. For instance, the line:

  ```
  Hello \vbox{\hsize=1.2cm\parindent=0pt how are\par you?} world
  ```

  typesets:   [image]
- A `\vcenter` aligns the center of the box with what TeX knows as the center of the math axis (it works only in math-mode), which roughtly speaking centers the box, so this:

  ```
  Hello $\vcenter{\hsize=1.2cm\parindent=0pt how are\par you?}$ world
  ```

  typesets:   [image]
- A `\vtop` sets the baseline of the entire box to match the baseline of the first (top) line of the box, so the line:

  ```
  Hello \vtop{\hsize=1.2cm\parindent=0pt how are\par you?} world
  ```

  typesets:   [image]

Now, back to your case: If you use `b` (`\vbox`), TeX will align the baselines of the last (bottom) lines of each box. The last line of the picture is at the bottom of the picture, and the baseline of the code is at the end of the code (due to the many wrappers added by `minted` and its machinery, this does not match the last line of code, but use your imagination and suppose it does ;-). TeX will thus align the base of the picture with the base of the code. Fair enough.

But what about `t`? TeX will align the first line in each box. The first line in the code is the first line of code (again, it's not, but bear with me here), and the first line in the picture is... the same as before. The box of the picture has a single line, so for it `t` or `b` won't make a difference. However if you use `t` in the code too, you'll see the first line of code line up with the bottom of the picture. That's why using only `t` here will make it look worse.

---

And what do you do now? You trick TeX into thinking there is one line above the picture. If you add `\vspace{0pt}` TeX will go into vertical mode, create a line, and then put the picture in the next line. Now the box in the picture has two lines and the top line is above the picture. Now `t` will work:

> [image]

P.S.: I cheated.
I removed the `bgcolor` option from `minted` because it adds a bunch of unnecessary vertical spacing which would make the picture look bad :-)

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=lines,framesep=2mm, autogobble]{julia}
      he = Systems.henon()
      N, α = 100000, 2
      tr = trajectory(he, N)
      ε = estimate_boxsizes(tr)
      ε = 10 .^ (-6:0.25:0)
      H = genentropy.(α, ε, Ref(tr))
      plot(-log10.(ε), log10.(H))
    \end{minted}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if both my figures are `minted`, and I want to align their last lines? Adding `\vspace{0pt}` to both does not appear to help

Comment: @Eric Use `\begin{subfigure}[b]`, then no `\vspace` trick is needed

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if one sub figure has a caption has multiple lines.

Comment: Though wrapping each `minted` in an extra `{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}` did the trick